# Why can't TensorFlow's Dataset API know the dimensions of a TFRecord?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a set of 3 x 32 x 32 images that I have converted into a single TF Record file.

When I try to read the data using the Dataset API and look at the shape of the operation, I get this:

```
'image1': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext_2:0' shape=(?, ?, ?, ?) dtype=float32>
```

In contrast, I have another 1 x 32 x 32 images that I load into memory and read from the dataset. In this case, the dataset is able to determine the dimensions of the image:

```
image2': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext_2:2' shape=(?, 1, 32, 32) dtype=float32>
```

This is a problem because I can't perform a convolution on `image1` because the channel dimension is None. I get this error:

```
ValueError: The channel dimension of the inputs should be defined. Found `None`.
```

Is this a bug or did I mess up when i encode the images or decode the images?

This is the code I used to do the encoding and decoding:

```
class img_to_tf_record_writer:
    # based on code from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/how_tos
    # /reading_data/convert_to_records.py
    def __init__(self, images, labels, save_path):
        """

        :param images: A numpy array of images (number of images, channels, height, width) to convert to a tfrecord
        :param labels: A numpy array of labels to convert to a tfrecord
        :param save_path: A string representing the full path to save the tfrecord
        """
        self.images = images
        self.labels = labels
        self.filename = save_path

    def _int64_feature(self, value):
        return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))

    def _bytes_feature(self, value):
        return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))

    def encode(self):
        if os.path.isfile(self.filename):
            print(f'{self.filename} exists')
            return

        num_examples, depth, rows, cols = self.images.shape

        print(f'Converting to TF Record format')

        with tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(self.filename) as writer:
            for i in range(num_examples):
                image_raw = self.images[i].tostring()
                label = int(self.labels[i])

                feature_dict = {
                    'height': self._int64_feature(rows),
                    'width': self._int64_feature(cols),
                    'depth': self._int64_feature(depth),
                    'label': self._int64_feature(label),
                    'image_raw': self._bytes_feature(image_raw)
                }
                example = tf.train.Example(
                    features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature_dict)
                )
                writer.write(example.SerializeToString())

        print(f'Finished converting to TF Record format')

    @staticmethod
    def decode(serialized_example):
        # Based on code from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/how_tos/
        # reading_data/fully_connected_reader.py
        features = tf.parse_single_example(
            serialized_example,
            features={
                'image_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
                'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
                'height': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
                'width': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
                'depth': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)
            }
        )

        image_shape = tf.stack([features['depth'], features['height'], features['width']])
        image = tf.decode_raw(features['image_raw'], tf.float32)
        image = tf.reshape(image, image_shape)

        label = tf.cast(features['label'], tf.int32)

        return image, label
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `width` and `height` as well as `depth` from the tfrecord itself. Therefore your image shape is dynamic. It knows the shape after reading one record. But it can't know the shape at the time you are building the graph, and that is I am assuming you are seeing the error.

In TensorFlow you are generally working with a static graph. But a dynamic input like that wouldn't be very practical in general as the number of weights would change.

I don't know the reason for your dynamic image shape. Usually the image shape within TFRecords would match the model. The best option for you might be to resize the image before you feed it to the model. You might have to agree on the number of channels to use.

Comment: Do you mean I can read the TFRecords file using the Dataset API and then resize it to some fixed dimension using the `map()` function?

Comment: Yes, see https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/image#Resizing - you can use for example `tf.image.resize_bicubic`. Alternatively resize the images before putting them into the tfrecords.